# Suppression State Error C2440 'return': cannot convert from '_Ty2 *' to 'std::pair<T *,unsigned int>'

Tags: c++, c++17

i have a source code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Tes 
{
    unordered_map < string, pair<T*, unsigned int>> m_resources;
public:
    pair<T*, unsigned int> Find(const string& l_id)
    {
        auto itr = m_resources.find(l_id);

        return (itr != m_resources.end() ? &itr->second : nullptr);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Tes<int> t;
    pair<int*, unsigned int> tes2 = t.Find("tes");
}
```

it has error in return itr in my template. can anybody help why this happen??
i use the unordered_map in this code.and using pair.

Comment: The `Find` method is declared to return a `pair<T*, unsigned int>` but you're returning `&itr->second`, which is not a `pair<T*, unsigned int>`.

Comment: so what i should return in example?

Comment: You're attempting to return a `std::pair<T*, unsigned int>*` but the function declaration expects a `std::pair<T*, unsigned int>` to be returned.

Comment: so what the itr should be write in this example

Comment: "So what should I return?" First you have to tell us what you want to return. Then we can suggest ways of returning it. But we can't tell you what to return. It's your function. You decide what it returns.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you're attempting to return a pointer `std::pair<T*, unsigned int>*` but your member function declaration expects a `std::pair` to be returned by value `std::pair<T*, unsigned int>`.

To fix the issue you can change the function declaration to expect a `std::pair<T*, unsigned int>*` to be returned.

```
template<typename T>
class Tes 
{        
public:
    pair<T*, unsigned int>* Find(const string& l_id)
    {
        auto itr = m_resources.find(l_id);
        return itr != m_resources.end() ? &itr->second : nullptr;
    }
private:
    unordered_map<string, pair<T*, unsigned int>> m_resources;
};

int main()
{
    Tes<int> t{};
    pair<int*, unsigned int>* tes2 = t.Find("tes");
}
```